# Outlook.com using API but without authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using outlook.com account using API, but when i am trying to send mail or receive mail than every time authentication is compulsory but without authentication can i send mail or receive mail with outlook API? Please Helping me if have you any idea about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [following manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations):

> Like other Outlook REST API, for every request to the Mail API, you should include a valid access token. Getting an access token requires you to have registered and identified your app, and obtained the appropriate authorization. You can [find out more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/use-outlook-rest-api#ShortRegAuthWorkflow) about some streamlined registration and authorization options for you. Keep this in mind as you proceed with the specific operations in the Mail API.

Comment: NO, i want it without access token, is it possible or not?

Comment: @roshnibrahmbhatt I guess not?

Comment: Ok thanks, now one thing i want refresh token with it. how to get it?

Comment: @roshnibrahmbhatt that is a whole other question :)

Comment: @roshnibrahmbhatt Then you should probably post a question with the corresponding title. Anyway, [in the same manual](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-tokens/) it goes something like this: "In order to receive a refresh in a token response, your app must request & be granted the offline_acesss scope. To learn more about the offline_access scope, refer to the consent & scopes [article here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-scopes/)."